# If $p \equiv 3\pmod{\!4}$ and $q=2p+1$ are prime then $2^p-1$ is prime $\!\iff\! p= 3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p and q be prime numbers with $p \equiv 3 $(mod 4) and $q=2p+1$.

> Prove that $2^p-1$ is prime if and only if $p= 3$.

The hint is by way of contradiction assume $p \neq 3$ then conclude that $q$ divides $2^p-1$.

I am having trouble reaching this contradiction. If I let $p=4k+3$ where k is some integer not equal to 0, then q can be expressed as $4(2k+1) +3$ meaning it is also $\equiv 3 $(mod 4). I'm not sure if this helps or not though.

Comment: Put "only if" in your title.  I read it as "prove $2^p -1$ is prime if $p=3$" which the same as "prove $2^3 - 1$ is prime" which is ... not a difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

What a mess. Have you heard about quadratic reciprocity ?

If $p,q=2p+1$ are primes then (by Fermat little theorem) $2^p  \equiv 2^{(q-1)/2} \equiv\pm 1 \bmod q$. It is $+1$ [iff $2$ is a square $\bmod q$ iff $q \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B12_and_the_second_supplement). Thus $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4 \implies q \equiv 7 \bmod 8 \implies 2^p \equiv 1 \bmod q \implies q | 2^p-1$