# Where did Lagrange prove that if $p\equiv 3\bmod{4}$ and $q=2p+1$ are primes, then $q$ divides $2^p-1$?

Tags: number-theory, math-history

It is said that Lagrange proved in 1775 that

> if $p\equiv 3\bmod{4}$ and $q=2p+1$ are primes, then $q$ divides $2^p-1$

but I have not been able to find the source, where he did this. Can you help me?

Edit: This is said in many places, for example, at

- https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/MerDiv2.html
- https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642303
- https://books.google.fi/books?id=zUCK7FT4xgAC&pg=PA65 (Paulo Ribenboim: The Little Book of Bigger Primes, p. 65)

Comment: I don't know a reference, but this is an immediate consequence of Quadratic Reciprocity.  More precisely, of the classification of primes for which $2$ is a square. 
 See, for instance, the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500135/let-p-and-q-be-prime-numbers-with-p-equiv-3-mod-4-and-q-2p1-prove-that).

Comment: `\bmod` for the binary mod operator, not `\mod` (it doesn't leave that weird extra space up front); if you want $p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, with the parentheses, write `p\equiv 3\pmod{4}`.

Comment: The years given there are Euler 1750 and Lagrange 1775. Check out which number theoretical articles Euler and Lagrange wrote in these years (there's actually only one in each case) and then read them (Euler is available in English, and so is at least the first part of Lagrange's recherches).

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Thank you for your suggestions. Actually, I think Euler stated his observation already in a paper published in 1738 (presented already in 1732) "Observationes de theoremate quodam Fermatiano aliisque ad numeros primos spectantibus" (downloadable at https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/26/). I browsed through (an English translation of) Lagrange's "Recherches d'Arithmétique" (downloadable at https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.14665). It's possible that the claim considered in my post is a corollary of one of his theorems stated in that work but I did not understand how.

Comment: Euler essentially stated that if $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo the prime $2m+1$, then $a^m+1$ is divisible by $2m+1$ (Thm. 11 in E134). At that time, he could not yet prove that $2$ is a square modulo $p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$. This was shown by Lagrange in his recherches.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Thank you, this was very helpful!

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Please feel free to post your explanation as an answer. I'd like to accept it. By the way, I think you mean $a^m-1$ instead of $a^m+1$.