# Let p and q be prime numbers with $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $q=2p+1$. Prove that $2^{p} - 1$ is prime only when $p=3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, mersenne-numbers

**Task:** Let p and q be prime numbers with $p \equiv 3 \ \pmod 4$ and $q=2p+1$. Prove that $2^{p} - 1$  is prime only when $p=3$.

This question has been asked on this forum for a long time, but I have some questions about the solution that was proposed. That's why I asked a new question, because I'm not sure if someone answered me under the comments of a post six years ago.
([that post is right here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500135/let-p-and-q-be-prime-numbers-with-p-equiv-3-mod-4-and-q-2p1-prove-that))

Do I understand correctly that in the solution proposed by ***reuns***, it was proved that $q$ divides $2^p - 1$ when $p \equiv 3 \ \pmod 4$, $q \equiv 7 \pmod  8$? And in this case, the number $2^p - 1$ will be composite, not prime. But then I don't understand at all, because when $p = 3: p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, $q \equiv 7 \pmod 8$, but the Mersenne number $2^p - 1 = 2^3 - 1 = 7$ will be prime, not composite.

And is it necessary to prove that $q \neq 2^p - 1$, when $p \neq 3$? If so, how to prove it?

If it will be easier for you not to answer my questions, but to write a solution to this task in more detail than ***reuns***, then I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: Your understanding is incomplete, because you didn't explicitly state the condition that $ q = 2p+1$ and is prime. It doesn't hold for any $p, q$ that satisfy $ p \equiv 3 \pmod 4, q \equiv 7 \pmod {8}$. $\quad$ The solution shows that under the conditions of 1/ $p$ prime, 2/ $p \equiv 3\pmod{4}$, 3/ $ q = 2p+1$, 4/ $q$ prime, , then (with some work) we can obtain that $ q \mid 2^p-1$. Hence, if $2^p - 1$ is prime, then $2^p -1 = q = 2p+1$, so $p$ has to be very small, and in particular, only $p = 3$ works.

Comment: Just to narrow: the only point you are unsure about is that $2p + 1 < 2^p -1$ for $p>3$?

Comment: Since $q=2p+1,$ if $q=2^p-1$ then $2^{p-1}=p+1.$ Prove by induction that this isn't possible for $p>3.$ And yes, the argument fails when $q\neq 2^p-1$ to conclude $2^p-1$ is not prime. Technically, you also need $q\neq 1,$ but that is obvious

Comment: @EricTowers I think OP is missing the argument of $ 2^p - 1 = q = 2p+1$, because they immediately jump to "$2^p-1$ will be composite, not prime".

Comment: Simply put, suppose $2^p \equiv - 1 \pmod {2p+1}$. Multiplying by 2, we note -2 is a quadratic residue mod $2p+1$, But, 2 is also a quadratic residue mod 2p+1, so that -1 is a quadratic residue mod 2p+1, Contradiction!

Comment: Thank you all! Thanks to your comments, the solution to this task became much clearer to me.